# Setting NODE_ENV variable in elasticbeanstalk

Tags: node.js, git, amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've created a file called **.elasticbeanstalk/environment.config** with the following in it:

```
option_settings:
  - option_name: NODE_ENV
    value: development
```

I'm also passing the process.env.NODE_ENV to the view so I can check the value

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var data = {
    env: process.env.NODE_ENV
  }
  res.render('upload',data);
});
```

On my local machine I get the value "local" which is what I've set it to. When I deploy to Amazons Elastic Beanstalk via `$ git aws.push` the value is empty.

Is there anything else I need to do for EB to recognise the NODE_ENV setting?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your .config file should be located in the `.ebextensions` directory, not `.elasticbeanstalk`.

Try it then, if that doesn't work, you can always use the console.

In the meantime, you can always use the [Elastic Beanstalk Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/home) which let's you add environment variables from its interface. To do so, just:

1. Open up your environment.
2. You'll see Dashboard, Configuration, Logs and more on the left. Click the Configuration link.
3. Then click the gear icon next to the **Software Configuration** block.
4. Scroll down and add a key/value for the Environment Properties.

Comment: Awesome stuff - think I took in too much at the same time and wasn't properly reading the docs.

Comment: I use the `Dockerrun.aws.json` to deploy the image that I built before. In this case, I can't access any of the env variables (both from UI and from .config) on the app.

Answer (score 8):

Other ways to set `environment variables` in elastic beanstalk are -

1. Create a config file in `.ebextensions` directory like `environmentalvar.config` and define variables in `option_settings` and include this file into application bundle. ([Aws Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html))

   example -

   ```
   option_settings:
        aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
          NODE_ENV: production
   ```
2. By using elastic beanstalk command line tool. Command for set variable-

   `eb setenv VAR_NAME=VAR_VALUE`