# React Native Expo Environment Variables

Tags: react-native, environment-variables, expo

So I'm happy with the concept of environment variables as explained in this article and others
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-gracefully-use-environment-variables-in-a-react-native-app/

Great, I've got my SOMETHING="something" stored so I can just use env.SOMETHING or whatever

The part I'm a little lost on **is where you keep the live variables**?

I would rather not do a solution like this as it seems you are still keeping your keys quite public and that you are just choosing based on the environment with if statements

[Manage environment with expo react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57494552/manage-environment-with-expo-react-native)

For example with an Express App deployment we have, we specify

```
let endPointURL = env.endPointURL
```

and then we keep a versoin of that variable locally and when it sits with AWS it is overridden by AWS servers as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26012083/setting-node-env-variable-in-elasticbeanstalk)

I was just wondering does something like that exist for Android and iOS builds (on the respective stores) or through Expo?

*Thanks all*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Honestly I think the way they go about it is a little silly. There may be a better way to go about than this, but I think I followed their documentation suggestions.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/release-channels/#using-release-channels-for-environment-variable-configuration

They have a code snippet suggesting you create a function to look at the release configuration itself.

I interpreted it that you might do something like the code below and store your environment variables in a `variables.js` file and pull in your environment variables as such.

```js
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export const prodUrl = "https://someapp.herokuapp.com";

const ENV = {
  dev: {
    apiUrl: "http://localhost:3000"
  },
  staging: {
    apiUrl: prodUrl
  },
  prod: {
    apiUrl: prodUrl
  }
};

function getEnvVars(env = "") {
  if (env === null || env === undefined || env === "") return ENV.dev;
  if (env.indexOf("dev") !== -1) return ENV.dev;
  if (env.indexOf("staging") !== -1) return ENV.staging;
  if (env.indexOf("prod") !== -1) return ENV.prod;
}

export default getEnvVars(Constants.manifest.releaseChannel);
```

Edit:

Now that Expo supports config file as `app.config.js` or `app.config.ts`, we can use the `dotenv`. Check this: https://docs.expo.io/guides/environment-variables/#using-a-dotenv-file

Comment: After a (long!) deep dive into how this is done, I'll select your answer @Caleb. What a shame there isn't a simpler mechanism for this! I've ended up keeping two folders - one for live and one for dev with a different folder for env variables that I just git push and pull to to keep the source code up to day. Very silly put it works! :'D

Comment: I was rather hoping I would be proven wrong. Oh well. Most of the answers are "just get off expo"

Comment: An alternative solution for @AshHogarth might be to keep both configuration folders in one repo, and have one file which switches between them when needed. Add this file to `.gitignore` and generate it each time you build. E.g. `config.now.js` simply contains `module.exports = require('./config.staging/index.js')`

Comment: I am trying that and I can say it does not work well, the expo web can get the new env, but the android and ios app are stuck with one I can't even change.

Answer (score 6):

A simpler approach would be to export the env object instead of the function:

```html
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { Platform } from "react-native";

const localhost =
 Platform.OS === "ios" ? "localhost:8080" : "10.0.2.2:8080";


const ENV = {
    dev: {
      apiUrl: localhost,
      amplitudeApiKey: null,
    },
    staging: {
      apiUrl: "[your.staging.api.here]",
      amplitudeApiKey: "[Enter your key here]",
      // Add other keys you want here
    },
    prod: {
      apiUrl: "[your.production.api.here]",
      amplitudeApiKey: "[Enter your key here]",
      // Add other keys you want here
    }
};

const getEnvVars = (env = Constants.manifest.releaseChannel) => {
  if (env === null || env === undefined || env === "" || env.indexOf("dev") !== -1) return ENV.dev;
  if (env.indexOf("staging") !== -1) return ENV.staging;
  if (env.indexOf("prod") !== -1) return ENV.prod;
}

const selectedENV = getEnvVars();

export default selectedENV;
```

```html
// Import
import env from '..xxx/utility/env';
```

Comment: You're solution is the same as the accepted answer except for that you break up the method call.  The accepted answer isn't returning a function.  It's returning the results of the function just like your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Surprised there weren't any answers that involved storing environment variables in a `.env` file with Expo.

I prefer storing my environment variables in a `.env` file because I don't want to commit certain variables to version control and hardwire them into my application code.

1. Create your `.env` file and add your environment variables
2. Install `dotenv`

```
npm install dotenv
```

3. In your `app.config.js` file, load the environment variables from the `.env` file via `dotenv`:

```js
require("dotenv").config();

export default {
    // config...
}
```

4. Expose the environment variables to the Expo runtime in the config in `app.config.js`:

```js
require("dotenv").config();

export default {
    // rest of config...
    extra: {
        ENV_VAR: process.env.ENV_VAR
    }
}
```

Now you can access your environment variables through the following:

```js
import Constants from "expo-constants";
const ENV_VAR = Constants.expoConfig.extra.ENV_VAR
```

**OPTIONAL:** TypeScript

To make using environment variables in our code a little nicer, lets create a typed helper utility to access the environment variables:

```js
import Constants from "expo-constants";

export interface Env {
  ENV_VAR: string;
}

/**
 * Environment variables exposed through `app.config.js`
 * An environment variable not there? Make sure it is explicitly defined in `app.config.js`
 */
export const env = Constants.expoConfig?.extra as Env;
```

Then you can simply access your environment variables from the env object:

```
const ENV_VAR = env.ENV_VAR
```

**OPTIONAL:** Throw an error if an environment variable is not set

This can be handy to prevent your app from running if an environment variable required for your app to properly function is not set.

In your `app.config.js`:

```js
// Validate all necessary environment variables are set
const checkForEnvVariable = (envVar) => {
  if (!process.env[envVar]) {
    throw Error(`${envVar} not set! Check env.md for more information`);
  }
};
[
  "ENV_VAR",
  // ...
].forEach((envVar) => checkForEnvVariable(envVar));
```

Answer (score 1):

Get it in your `ios`-generated file, based on `.env` file:

1. In `.env`, write down `GOOGLE_MAPS_API=abcde...`
2. `yarn add react-native-config`
3. `cd ios`
4. `pod install`
5. In your `Objective-C`-compiled code, for example, `AppDelegate.m`:

```
#import "ReactNativeConfig.h"
NSString *mapsApiKey = [ReactNativeConfig envFor:@"GOOGLE_MAPS_API"];
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:mapsApiKey];
```

Credits to: [ReactNative: Pass JS variable to AppDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48926249/reactnative-pass-js-variable-to-appdelegate) based on https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config.

<strike>`Android` should work as well, but haven't tested / followed https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config</strike>.
Edit: required steps for `Android`:

1. `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="@string/GOOGLE_MAPS_API"/>` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.
2. In `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':react-native-config'
project(':react-native-config').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-config/android')
```

right after `rootProject.name = 'XYZ'`

3. In `build.gradle`:
   `apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"` right below `import com.android.build.OutputFile` and `implementation project(':react-native-config')` right below `implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules`

Regarding "normal" usage in `.ts`, `.tsx`, `.js` files I'm declaring variables in `.env` based on https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv by declaring `"module:react-native-dotenv"` in `babel.config.js` in `plugins`, and it works like a charm like so:

```
import { ACCESS_TOKEN } from "@env";
...
headers: {
  Authorization: `Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
  Accept: "application/json",
},
```

**Edit: important** the `eas` build ignores `.gitignore`-declared variable, so if your `.env` is in `.gitignore` the production bundle won't have it included.

Comment: I've been breaking my head over this last part "eas build ignores .gitignore-declared variable".

Comment: @Gijsriet, I did as well :)

Comment: Now, there's a warning if your build fails with `eas`: * Android build failed:
"google-services.json" is missing, make sure that the file exists. Remember that EAS Build only uploads the files tracked by git. Use EAS secrets to provide EAS Build with the file. Learn more* It redirects to https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variables/#how-to-upload-a-secret-file-and

Answer (score 0):

To pass environmental variables from your shell environment, without `.env` files, you can leverage the [`expoConfig.extra`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#extra) functionality

#### step 1: expose the variable

update your `app.config.js` or `app.config.ts` to expose the environmental variable under the `extra` namespace

for example, to expose an environmental variable named `STAGE`:

```js
// app.config.ts

import { ExpoConfig, ConfigContext } from 'expo/config';

export default (context: ConfigContext): ExpoConfig => ({
  // ... the rest of your config

  // https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/constants/#constantsmanifest;
  extra: {
    STAGE: process.env.STAGE, // expose a stage env variable to the app
  },
});
```

#### step 2: access the variable

access the exposed variable via the `expo-constants` module

for example, to access the `STAGE` variable exposed in the example above

```js
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const stage = Constants.expoConfig?.extra?.STAGE;
```

#### step 3: clear your cache

unfortunately, as of the time of writing, expo's cache seems to also be caching the `extra` values

therefore, if you those values are changing, you must start expo with the `--clear` setting to clear the cache

```bash
expo start --clear
```