Expo stuck on: "Welcome to Expo" screen
So I've just installed Expo SDK51: "expo": "~51.0.8", and want to build something. But I have a weird error or bug that I only see the "Welcome to Expo" large text with a prompt to create a file in "app" dir. Although this should not occus since when I look up for the text it is nowhere in the files and the app dir already has the basic tab bar files with parallax. I have never seen this occur and I have no idea how to get out of this.
Yes I have tried clean run, yes I've tried restarting and so on... this is just weird.

Are you using a development build?

But why? I just want to quick test something in the Expo Go! Nothing that would require native build

A development build is required, it gives you the option to make live changes. This only has to be done once

run the following command npx expo run:android

youre missing the point, the dev build is not required for simple app as I said before! while it may get rid of the bug I want to address this exact scenario, since when I made a new project and installed the same packages it works now without dev build so don't spread misinformation

Did your project use react-native-dotenv or any other env Babel plugins? According to the Expo SDK 51 changelog:

react-native-dotenv is not compatible with expo-router. If you are using the react-native-dotenv Babel plugin, it will overwrite expo-router configuration environment variables and you'll see the empty state "Welcome to Expo" screen. We are tracking the incomptibility in expo/expo#28933, but we recommend removing the library and Babel plugin, and instead using Expo CLI's built-in support for .env files (learn more).

I had the problem when I upgraded my project from Expo SDK 49 to Expo SDK 51, so I erased module:react-native-dotenv from babel.config.js and removed the library, but it turned out I also had babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables, so I had to remove that too. After refactoring to use Expo environment variables, my project worked fine.
Hope this helps :)

So I had the same issue but solved it, this way following the steps below:

npm uninstall react-native-dotenv

Copy and paste the code below in your babel.config.js:
module.exports = function (api) {
    api.cache(true);
    return {
      presets: ['babel-preset-expo']
    };
};


Access all your environment variables like this process.env.X e.g. GOOGLE_API_KEY, make sure to use process.env.X everywhere in your application

Then run this command: npx expo start -c
to start your expo app and it will work just fine


You can read here for more knowledge: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/environment-variables/

process.env. doesn't work in react native because it doesn't run on Node

I've been struggling to make progress with my project because it's currently stuck on the frustrating "Welcome to Expo" screen. After working on this small project for two days, I encountered this issue and couldn't find any steps to resolve it. However, I discovered that the problem was caused by the plugin ["module:react-native-dotenv"]. Removing this plugin solved the issue, allowing me to move forward with my project.

thanks man I build the same app 3 time because of this

This ended my pain thank mate

I have got some work stuck on that awful "Welcome to Expo" Screen.
For now, my suggestion or a workaround would be to downgrade the expo version to 50.0.18 or atleast to 51.0.0
EDIT: I am using 51.0.10 at this point, it seems to be working good

Thank you, it was a fresh new app so not THAT big deal but I can't imagine dealing with that on an existing project... What I did was I just created the app again and it works but it's definitely weird behaviour. Even worse is expo support (more like is not :))

Many people offered solutions to my problem, but none worked. Then, someone suggested checking the Expo SDK 51 documentation. Following the guide
https://docs.expo.dev/guides/environment-variables/,
I was finally able to upgrade my Expo project from version SDK 50 to 51!
It wasn't easy though. First, I had to manually update all the outdated packages listed in my terminal output. Then, I made sure to address almost all the warnings I encountered (ideally clearing them completely).
Finally, after all that effort, running npx expo start -c got my project working again!

Uninstalling the react-native-dotenv package and then removing react-native-dotenv from the babel.config.js file.
Then using the command npx expo start -c fixed the issue for me.

This action works successfully, but how can I use the .env file?

I just tried this fork: https://github.com/cchoi94/react-native-dotenv proposed at the end of the issue thread https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv/issues/501, and it works with the latest Expo SDK version "expo": "~52.0.20" that I am using.
npm install cchoi94/react-native-dotenv

@Lhony
There are also other ways to read environment variables without using react-native-dotenv. For example, the Expo documentation : https://docs.expo.dev/guides/environment-variables/) shows how you can use process.env. For additional approaches, you can perhaps refer to this StackOverflow discussion for a start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58270059/react-native-expo-environment-variables.

@stackingtabs Yes thanks you after this issue i found your solution
